# Определить из Сервиса запущено ли Активити

Tags: android, activity, service

Из Активити запущен сервис, в котором запускается таймер.
Когда таймер закончит отсчет, нужно проверить, запущено ли Активити *(за это время пользователь может его закрыть, может не закрыть, может закрыть и снова открыть*). В зависимости от этого, либо сервис сам останавливается, либо в Активити передается сообщение о том, что нужно нажать кнопку остановки. 
У меня для того ,что бы сервис знал о состоянии Активити, оно отправляет ему сообщения `startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class).putExtra("Mode", 0[1]));`
каждый раз при запуске и при закрытии. 
Вопрос: Есть ли более эффективный метод проверки из сервиса, запущено ли породившее его Активити? Если нет, откуда лучше отправлять сообщение startService `( OnCreate/OnDestroy, OnResume/OnPause)`?

Answer (score 4):

При завершении работы отправьте уведомление в активити (бродкастом или через EventBus) и создайте задачу через 2 секунды остановить сервис.

Из активити при получении уведомления отправляйте подтверждение. Сервис, при получении подтверждения может отменить задачу остановки самого себя. Отсутствие подтверждения считайте отсутствием активити.

Comment: Тогда совсем дилетантский вопрос. Нет ли отрицательных моментов в посылке бродкаста, если адресат не существует?

Comment: santfos, нет отрицательных моментов нет.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант запустить [Bound Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) и при вызове `Activity.onDestroy()` известить `Service` о своей гибели. Так что к моменту завершения сервиса у него всегда будет информация о том жив ли `Activity`, который его запустил.

Comment: Это почти то же самое. То есть, мы надеемся, что метод "OnDestroy"  Активити корректно выполнится и информация дойдет до сервиса.   Интересен вариант, когда сервис сам бы мог запросить существование Активити.